# Async web calls - needed configuration

Tags: .net, asp-classic, asynchronous

I am working on adding an Async web method to an existing ASP web service.
I will be using SoapHttpClientProtocol and begininvoke to call the async method, passing an asynccallback object.

My question is - do i need to make any configuration changes to my client \ server application? I do not fully understand how this async calls work - does the client application keep listening to port waiting for response? If so, do i need to make sure a port is open in firewall for client machines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little light on detail.  The inferences (which could be wrong due to this lack of detail) are that you have .NET client making calling in to a web service presented by a Classic ASP application.

You are considering using the `BeginInvoke` in a sub-class of `SoapHttpClientProtocol` to make the calls asynchronous from your clients point of view.

On the basis that my inferences are correct you need do nothing special to the ASP web service just add the service method as normal.  In fact if you considering calling an existing asynchronously you need do nothing to the server side code at all.  The "asynchronicity" is entirely a client-side artifice where the client APIs execute a callback when the request is complete.

Its probably better to understand how synchronous calls work because in fact they are more "artificial" than the apparently more complex asynchronous calls.   First and foremost **all** operations that perform some network I/O **will** be by necessity *asynchronous*.   At some point the current thread executing will have nothing further to do while it waits an eternity (from a modern CPU's point of view) for an I/O operation to complete.

So all web services will actually be asychronous without you needing to anything special with config or firewalls.  Its just that the typical developer friendly apis will **block** the current thread while the IO completes and often use the function semantic to *return* a response.

The only real difference with an asychronous call is that the thread doesn't block once the I/O operation is underway instead it will just return.  When the I/O operation has complete it will simply call the provided callback method.